# How do I test a component that subscribes to a service?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, observable

I'm relatively new to unit testing in Angular. I'm using Jasmine and I find the API to be vague. I'm trying to write good tests for my component, but I'm getting stuck on how to test a component that subscribes to data from a service.

// component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.dispatch(this.loadDatagridDataAction({data: this.authorizations}));

    this.authorizationService.initAuthorizations();
    this.authorizationService.authorizations.subscribe(authorizations => {
        this.realAuthorizations = authorizations;
        this.realAuthorizations.results.forEach(authorization => {

            const formatAuthorization = {};

            if (authorization.number) {
                formatAuthorization['number'] = authorization.number;
            }

            if (authorization.status) {
                formatAuthorization['status'] = authorization.status;

            }

            if (authorization.requesting_provider) {
                const requestingProvider = flattenObject(authorization.requesting_provider);
                formatAuthorization['requesting_provider'] = requestingProvider['name'];

            }

            if (authorization.servicing_provider) {
                const servicingProvider = flattenObject(authorization.servicing_provider);
                formatAuthorization['servicing_provider'] = servicingProvider['name'];

            }

            if (authorization.termination_date) {
                formatAuthorization['termination_date'] = authorization.termination_date;
            }

            this.formattedAuthorizations.push(formatAuthorization);
        });

    });

}

setActiveTab(tab) {
    this.store.dispatch(this.setActiveTabAction({tab}));
}

setActiveRow(row) {
    console.log(row);
}

setCurrentPage(page) {
    this.store.dispatch(this.setPaginatorCurrentPageAction({page}));
}

goBack(route) {
    console.log(route);
}
```

}

// service

```
export class AuthorizationService {

private _authorizations = new Subject<any>();

constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
) { }

public get authorizations() {
    return this._authorizations.asObservable();
}

public getAuthorizations() {
    const auth = '/api/enrollment/tocs/';
    return this.http.get(auth);
}

public initAuthorizations() {
    this.getAuthorizations().subscribe(data => {
        this._authorizations.next(data);
    }, error => {
        console.log('Failed to get data', error);
    });
}
```

}

// unit test

```
describe('AuthorizationsReferralsComponent', () => {
let component: AuthorizationsReferralsComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<AuthorizationsReferralsComponent>;
let storeMock;
let configurationServiceMock;
let authorizationMockService;

beforeEach(async(() => {
    storeMock = {
        select: jasmine.createSpy('select'),
        dispatch: jasmine.createSpy('dispatch'),
    };

    authorizationMockService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getAuthorizations', 'initAuthorizations', 'authorizations']);

    configurationServiceMock = {
        getTemplateConfiguration: () => {}
    };

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ AuthorizationsReferralsComponent ],
        imports: [SidebarTableViewModule,  HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [
            {
                provide: Store,
                useValue: storeMock
            },
            {
                provide: ConfigurationService,
                useValue: configurationServiceMock,
            },
            {
                provide: AuthorizationService,
                useValue: authorizationMockService
            },

        ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    HEROES = [
      {id: 1, name: 'SpiderDude', strength: 8},
      {id: 2, name: 'Wonderful Woman', strength: 24},
      {id: 3, name: 'SuperDude', strength: 55}
    ];

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AuthorizationsReferralsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
});

it('should create', () => {
    authorizationMockService.initAuthorizations.and.returnValue(of(HEROES));
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(fixture.componentInstance.realAuthorizations.length).toBe(3);
});
```

});

I receiving the following error `TypeError: this.authorizationService.authorizations.subscribe is not a function`

It appears that it thinks my `get authorizations()` function is not a function. How can I mock my service appropriately so I test the statements inside my subscribe?

```
 this.authorizationService.authorizations.subscribe(
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `get` from `get authorizations()`?

Comment: my function doesn't work and the test doesn't run

Comment: Check this [article](https://netbasal.com/testing-observables-in-angular-a2dbbfaf5329#63e7)

Answer (score 1):

Right now your mock service doesn't return anything and your component is expecting it to return an Observable.

In your test you need the below line:

```
authorizationMockService.authorizations.and.returnValue(of([])
```

Note that the above makes it return an Observable with an empty array.  If you want to return actual data you will need to set that up.

Comment: Looking at your test closer it looks like you probably want and.returnValue(of[HEROES]) instead of the empty array.